# Unable to parse img and name from amazon or flipkart pages using Jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsoup

I am unable to get main image and name for products at Amazon or Flipkart using Jsoup.

My java/jsoup code for the same is:

```
// For amazon
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).maxBodySize(1024*1024*10);
Document doc = connection.get();
Elements imgs = doc.select("img#landingImage");
Elements names = doc.select("span#productTitle");

// For flipkart
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).maxBodySize(1024*1024*10);
Document doc = connection.get();
Elements imgs = doc.select("h1.title");
Elements names = doc.select("img.productImage.current");
```

Can someone please point out what am I missing here?

URLs I have used are:

http://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-yoga-2-tablet-android-10-inch/p/itmeyqkznqa2zjf5?pid=TABEYQKXWAXMSGER&srno=b_2&offer=ExchangeOffer_LenovoYoga.&ref=9ea008ab-ae95-4f52-8ef7-3ef1a54947ae

and

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LZGBU3Y/ref=s9_psimh_gw_p504_d0_i5?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=0ESK1KNE31TBRVC8115Q&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1970559082&pf_rd_i=desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LZGBU3Y)

Also, I would like to do this parsing on the front end if possible using javascript and jquery.

Is there a way to do the same?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I tried your code and it's working. Which version of Jsoup are using?

Comment: Really? Can you please post your full code and the output here?

Comment: I am using jsoup-1.8.1.jar version (downloaded yesterday from jsoup.org website)

Comment: I do not get any exception, but the result of all the four **doc.select()** calls above are arrays with size 0. I am running this on GAE (Google AppEngine)

Comment: No point in posting the program, I mean it's just a main where I just call your code, nothing else. Try setting a userAgent (I didn't, but the userAgent differs from case to case, and it might happens that my default one just works).

Comment: Try this http://www.whatsmyua.com/ to get your browser's user agent. You can set it like this `Document doc = connection.userAgent("").get();`

Comment: I converted this to a standalone program and voila, it worked. Any ideas why its not working in app-engine?

Comment: I haven't used GAE before so no. Did you try setting the userAgent? It's the only thing that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.

Jsoup in GAE works when we use the URL fetch service using java.net.URL as:

```
private String read(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObj .openStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().length() > 0)
            sbuf.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sbuf.toString();
}
```

And then you use regular Jsoup as:

```
String html = read(url);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Doing the above works very well.